# How to get the sumary from preferences

Tags: android, preferences

One question:
I have a EditTextPreference to let the user type in a default path for the app.

How can I manage that the new value is to be seen in the preferencefragment I use?

After the user clicked ok in the preference window to complete the new settings I want to write the new path as a summary below the title.

I have tried already experiencing with the onSharedPreferenceChanged but it did not work. I do not know how to get access to the edit field from the popup window where the users text is in.

Hope to find some help
Andreas!

Edit:
Here is the source code for the whole PreferenceFragment I used and modified with the suggestions of Rustam. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
package com.example.wbsettings;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class PreferenceFrag extends PreferenceFragment 
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

public static final String KEYVAL = "startpath"; 
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    EditTextPreference prefUrl = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(KEYVAL);
    prefUrl.getEditText().setHint("default path");

    //>> Here the app crashed when I debug it
         ------------------------------------ 
    prefUrl.setSummary(sp.getString(KEYVAL, ""));

}//onCreate

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
        pref.setSummary(etp.getText());

    }
}//onSharedPreferenceChanged

}
```

What I also do not understand in your example: Where is the preferences to register with the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? I mean as of now I never reach the onSharedPreferenceChanged procedure because of the crash. But when I make the statement a comment and the app is running and finished I have never been stopped at the breakpoint I set within the onSharedPreferenceChanged procedure.

Another question: 
What is the best practice here to answer a comment if the answer becomes too long for another comment? I tried to open an answer to my own question. But a pop up informed me that this is not the way it should be. So what to do?

Regards Andreas!

Comment: one simple question: Have You registered Your preferences to the OnSharedPreferencesChangedListener? Most poeple forget this...

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes i did it - after I forgot it also before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `menu_setting.xml` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"

        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>

</menu>
```

your `preference.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Enter path"
        android:key="prefPath"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Path Setting" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

your `PreferenceFrag` should look like this :

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class PreferenceFrag extends PreferenceFragment
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

public static final String KEYVAL = "prefPath"; 
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

    EditTextPreference prefPath = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(KEYVAL);
    prefPath.getEditText().setHint("sdcard/path");

    // Here the app crashed when I debug it

     SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();

         prefPath.setSummary(sp.getString(KEYVAL, ""));



}//onCreate


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
        pref.setSummary(etp.getText());

    }
}//onSharedPreferenceChanged

}
```

your `PreferenceActivity` :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PreferenceActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                new PreferenceFrag()).commit();
 }

}
```

your `MainActivity` :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }

        return true;
    }



}
```

finally `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.preferencetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.preferencetest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.preferencetest.PreferenceActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Many thanks for that interesting idea. I'll try it later this day and hope it'll work.

Comment: Hello Rustam,
sorry for the late reply - I was busy with other things the last days.
Sorry but your code did not work. It crashed when I came to
`prefUrl.setSummary(sp.getString(KEYVAL, ""));`
I have edit my question to show the whole source code I use for the FraqmentPreferences. May be you can see the reason for the crash?
Andreaas

Comment: put this `SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();` before `prefUrl.setSummary(sp.getString(KEYVAL, ""));`

Comment: Hi Rustam - yes now it works. Thanks for the whole source. I am a little bit confused about the extra PreferenceActivity. Why is it not possible to use the PreferenceFragment directly within the "onOptionsItemSelected"? Normally I do not like the idea to work with another activity and this is also what was recommended by Google Developer. Could you please explain me? 
Many Thanks and of course I'll vote up your answer. Have a nice time
Andreas

Comment: Sorry - I am not allowed to vote your answer up. They told me it needs 15 reputations and I only have 9!