# boolean SharedPreferences always loading default values

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I've a strange issue with **SharedPreferences** and boolean.
I've set this code in my xml:

xml:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
             android:key="onlywifiupload"
             android:defaultValue="true"
             android:summary="@string/summary_onlywifiupload"
             android:title="@string/title_onlywifiupload" 
      />
```

and from the Java code, I'm calling:

```
 boolean onlywifiupload =  pref.getBoolean("onlywifiupload", true);
```

Even the checkbox is checked or unchecked, in onlywifiupload there's always true.
Same with setting:

```
 boolean onlywifiupload =  pref.getBoolean("onlywifiupload", false);
```

It seems the default value is always loaded instead of checked values.

Comment: What is CheckBoxPreference ?? There is no such type of widget or Resource name

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html

Comment: check this link  hope it will help you.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865048/how-to-get-the-sumary-from-preferences/25865697#25865697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to make it working is:

```
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    onlywifiupload = mPrefs.getBoolean("onlywifiupload", true);
```

don't know why I need to call getDefaultSharedPreferences from PrefenceManager object

Before that, I was calling the preferences in this way:

```
    pref = getSharedPreferences("AppPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Actually this makes sense since the `PreferenceActivity`/`PreferenceFragment` use the default SharedPreferences file. That's why it didn't work for you with your custom SharedPrefs file.